# Form.ShowDialog() Without Destroying Handle

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I am trying to show a form using Form.ShowDialog as shown below:

```
var f = new Form();
if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     ...
}
...
if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     ...
}
```

The issue is the OnHandleDestroyed is called once a dialog result is returned and the form is closed.

- Why do I care about OnHandleDestroyed? I have an OpenGL control on the form, and it disposes the Context when OnHandleDestroyed is called.
- Why don't I dispose of the form, and use ShowDialog on the new form? I am trying to reuse the form as loading the form is slow - but populating it with data is quick.

So the question is: Is it possible to use ShowDialog() without closing the form (and hiding it instead) OR to show a form modally using Show() and Hide()?

Comment: You could write your own logic to hide the form is input is given

Comment: But how do I keep it modal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide form instead of closing when close button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021681/hide-form-instead-of-closing-when-close-button-clicked)

Comment: @Sinatr, it's not a duplicate of that one because I specifically want the form to be Modal.

Comment: Don't close it then. You have to choose: either recreate opengl stuff every time or .. don't close the form. There are the ways to make modeless form modal, look e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567719/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr - Sorry, I mean that I want it to be modal when it is shown (no other form other than its children can receive input). Once hidden, it is no longer modal.

Comment: That may work. Let me give that a go.

Comment: Pay close attention to the comments in that linked answer.  That solution requires the use of `DoEvents` and that is a known bad practice, because it is very hard to use without nasty side-effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you show a form using [`ShowDialog`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6108), after closing the form [`DestroyHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.destroyhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) will be called automatically.

To prevent the behavior you can override `DestroyHandle` method and write your own logic.

**Example**

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    protected override void DestroyHandle()
    {
        if (!Modal || Disposing)
            base.DestroyHandle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to dispose your modal dialogs when you don't need them anymore. For more information take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834).

Comment: Works great Reza! Solves my exact problem.